# Ros1_bridge not mapping custom fields with different names even with yaml file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the bridge and all of my messages are correctly mapped except for 1 where I had to change the name from the ros1 version of the message (ros2 does not allow capital letters).

Here is the ros2 version

```
float32 velocity
float32 current
uint8 command_flag
float32 r_jnt
```

Here is the ros1 version

```
float32 velocity
float32 current
uint8 commandFlag
float32 R_jnt
```

Here is my yaml file

```
-
  ros1_package_name: 'edo_core_msgs'
  ros1_msg_name: 'JointState'
  ros2_package_name: 'edo_core_msgs'
  ros2_msg_name: 'JointState'
  fields_1_to_2: 
    R_jnt: 'r_jnt'
    commandFlag: 'command_flag'
    current: 'current'
    position: 'position'
    velocity: 'velocity'
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt (only the related part)

```
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
   
  ${msg_files}
  ${srv_files}
   
 )
 
 install(
  FILES mapping.yaml
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})


 ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)

ament_package()
```

Package.xml

```
  <export>
    <ros1_bridge mapping_rules="mapping.yaml"/> 
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
    
  </export>
```

My file structure looks like this

```
.
├─ ros1_msgs_ws
│  └─ src
│     └─ bridge_msgs
│        └─ msg
│           └─ JointCommand.msg
├─ ros2_msgs_ws
│  └─ src
│     └─ bridge_msgs
│        ├─ msg
│        │  └─ JointCommand.msg
│        └─ # YAML file if your custom interfaces have non-matching names
└─ bridge_ws
   └─ src
      └─ ros1_bridge
```

I am using Eloquent built from debian and am bridging to melodic. Im using ubuntu 18.04. Ive followed all the instructions for building very closely and have reproduced the error on mulptiple computers. The bridge builds and includes all my messages except this one. I am now trying to build eloquent from source.

One last thing tht may be related or not. I get error messages when I build the bridge in the format of this:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/eloquent/share/actionlib_msgs/cmake/actionlib_msgsConfig.cmake:29 (message):     
  Package 'actionlib_msgs' is deprecated (This package will be removed in a                                
  future ROS distro, once the ROS 1 bridge supports actions.)                                              
Call Stack (most recent call first):                                                                       
  CMakeLists.txt:106 (find_package)                                                                        
                                                                                                           
                                                                                                           
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:186 (add_library):                                                         
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target ros1_bridge because                                
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit                                        
  directories:                                                                                             
                                                                                                           
    runtime library [liburdfdom_sensor.so.1.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:     
      /opt/ros/eloquent/lib                                                                                
    runtime library [liburdfdom_model_state.so.1.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /opt/ros/eloquent/lib                                                                                
    runtime library [liburdfdom_model.so.1.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:      
      /opt/ros/eloquent/lib                                                                                
    runtime library [liburdfdom_world.so.1.0] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:      
      /opt/ros/eloquent/lib                                                                                
                                                                                                           
  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364971/ros1_bridge-not-mapping-custom-fields-with-different-names-even-with-yaml-file/) by [maclo4](https://answers.ros.org/users/59330/maclo4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-11-06**:
I don't know if this is related, but `position` seems to be present in yaml, but not in msg.

**Comment by [maclo4](https://answers.ros.org/users/59330/maclo4/) on 2020-11-06**:
Scared me for a sec but that’s just a typo. Position is in the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: we got it working by changing the bridges cmakelist and package.xml, along with adding the yaml file to the bridge package *shrug*

---

Originally posted by [maclo4](https://answers.ros.org/users/59330/maclo4/) with karma: 26 on 2020-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BananaaGorilla98](https://answers.ros.org/users/83742/bananaagorilla98/) on 2021-09-05**:
Hi there,

I am facing the same question. Could you provide more details for your solution? It would be helpful! Thanks!